# Does Mists of Pandaria include any credit for gameplay time on a WoW subscription?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

My friend purchased a MoP expansion. He said that Gamestop told him that the expanison comes with 1 free month of game play for World of Warcraft. I have been looking throughout every possible WoW site possiblee, but I am not seeing it anywhere. Is this true or just a rumor?

Comment: Your friend was given incorrect information.  There isn't a single case of any of the expansions giving 30 days free.  Only the original purchase of the game has ever given 30 days free.  This is a 100% FALSE rumor, there is NO truth to it, my suggestion is not to shop at GameStop in the future.

Answer (score 7):

**It's only a rumor.** Though each vendor may give different *pre-order* bonuses for ordering from them (e.g., Amazon offers you a key to gain access to the MoP beta), Blizzard isn't actually offering any particular incentive themselves.

Comment: Aren't the pet and mount only for the Collector's Edition, not for preordering?

Comment: Ah, correct. And your question has led me to remember another point. Editing my response.

Comment: @TerranceShaw - The vendors are not allowed to give different bonuses.  The reward bonuses for ordering MoP from Amazon and GameStop is exactly the same.  The collectors edition (retail) and digital deluxe edition( only through Blizzard ) have the exact same digital rewards.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Mists of Pandaria does not include any "game time".  No prior expansion (BC, WotLK, Cata) included "game time" with purchase.

You do get "game time" with the purchase of the base game, or with purchases that include the base game (such as Battle Chest offers).

Answer (score 3):

[No](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/5492350087#3). WoW expansions [do not come](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/authentication-key-faq#q9) with game time.